# Is that possible to work with Double.NaN values in Azure Storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Good day.
I try understand if it's possible to create requests to AzureStorage with filter by Double.NaN value (C# language).

I create DynaimcTableEntity as

```
string PK = NaN.ToString();
        string RK = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string ETag = "*";
        double value = NaN;

        DynamicTableEntity dte = new DynamicTableEntity(PK, RK,ETag,new Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>()
        {
            { "value", new EntityProperty(value)}
        });
```

And successfully insert it into the table.
PK: NaN, value: NaN.

But when I try to get the line by filter "value eq NaN" I get StorageException with RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation "One of the request inputs is out of range."

How to create filter like "ColumnName eq Double.NaN" correctly?

Comment: I am confirming whether Azure table support this scenario. Maybe some times delay, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @Jambor-MSFT , if it's not difficult, can you check the Double.PositiveInfinity and Double.NegativeInfinity values also? I suppose the same behaviour with Double.NaN, but MSFT hints you have access to truth.